# Charts in Highcharts JS v4.0.4 do not load completely

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently using Highcharts JS v4.0.4 (2014-09-02) [yes, we need to upgrade] and I noticed that sometimes our charts do not load all the way. For instance, on loading a page, I see something like this:

[image: Incomplete Chart]

But then I hover over the chart, and additional sections appear:

[image]

Is this a know issue with this version of Highcharts? I am curious to know if this is something that can be fixed in this version or if it is a known issue only fixed with an upgrade. I previously tried to upgrade to the latest version and it broke some of our charts, so we opted to wait, since we didn't need to upgrade, but now we have this issue.

Comment: Hi thehme, live example would be very useful in this case. You can create demo on jsfiddle with Highcharts v4.0.4, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qjkextd9/

Comment: @ppotaczek will try to put something together